# Listbox item value not saved to database

Tags: c#, asp.net, database

The codes are:

> ```
> protected void bn_add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
>     {
>         SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["FYP"].ConnectionString);
>         string str;
>         SqlCommand com;
>         conn.Open();
>         for (int i = 0; i < listbox_selected.Items.Count; i++)
>         {
>             if (listbox_selected.Items[i].Selected == true)
>             {
>                 str = "INSERT INTO Competency_TechnicalSkill('" + listbox_selected.Items[i].ToString() + "')";
>                 com = new SqlCommand(str, conn);
>                 com.ExecuteNonQuery();
>             }
>         }
> ```

I have tried multiple times to insert data into Competency_TechnicalSkill database. However,
nothing got into the database, hence, would like to know if there are any solutions to solve this problem. Thank you!

Comment: what are you trying to do here? What fields in the table are you trying to fill by listbox items? Is it one field or multiple fields? [Have you checked these questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16983620/inserting-items-of-listbox-into-sql-server-database). If not, welcome to StackOverflow. Please check similar questions and try out accepted answers before you post.

Comment: i get this error: ExecuteNonQuery: Connection property has not been initialized.

Comment: Have you tested using one field and one value that your connection string is correct? (without listboxes and so on) Are you getting this error only when you are using Listbox insertion route?

Comment: The problem is clear here. Besides connection issue. See my answer and try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've refactored your code so it will work. Some comments are inline. I assume that you are inserting into a table with single column.

```
protected void bn_add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    // good idea to check if you have selected items
    if (listbox_selected.SelectedIndex == -1) return;

    // using will take care of closing and disposing
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["FYP"].ConnectionString))
    {
        conn.Open();
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
        {
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            // if your listbox is multiselect, all you need is to check 'selected items'
            foreach (ListItem item in listbox_selected.Items)
            {
                if (item.Selected == true)
                {
                    // here you didn't have 'values' in your sql query
                    command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Competency_TechnicalSkill values('" + item.ToString() + "')"; 
                    // if your table has more than one column you need to use: insert into table (col1) values ('data')            
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
        }
   }
}
```

Now, notice, if your `listbox` item is string already, no need to call `.ToString()` . I have not tested the code, but this should do it

Comment: I have gotten this error:
Error 3 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListBox' does not contain a definition for 'SelectedItems' and no extension method 'SelectedItems' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListBox' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\Fujitsu\Desktop\HCMS_FYPJ newcy\HCMS_FYPJ\HCMS\AdmCompetencyTechnicalSkill.aspx.cs 99 33 HCMS

Comment: @user3520985 I am sorry. For some reason I thought you use Win Forms. I've fixed my answer to asp.net code. I also added `using` on `command`, so it gets reused instead of creating new every time, for performance. Please, fix your question a little bit so it is removed from hold.

Comment: i have gotten this error: Error 4 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Selected' and no extension method 'Selected' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\Fujitsu\Desktop\HCMS_FYPJ newcy\HCMS_FYPJ\HCMS\AdmCompetencyTechnicalSkill.aspx.cs 111 30 HCMS

Comment: @user3520985 I know what the problem is. Because `listbox_selected.Items` is a collection. SO, I replaced `var item` with `ListItem item`. Another option would be casting like `((ListItem)item).Selected`. This is because collection holds objects and is not strong-typed. Please let me know how it works now.

Comment: thank you very much! the code can work already! :)